$A \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ and $B \subseteq A$ with $B\ \mu$-measurable and $\mu(A\setminus B) =0$ $\implies$ $A$ is $\mu$-measurable?
I have the following claim, that I almost don't believe is true:

Claim. $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ and $B \subseteq A$ with $B\ \mu$-measurable and $\mu(A\setminus B) =0$ $\implies$ $A$ is $\mu$-measurable

And because of that, I am unsure whether or not my proof is correct. I would appreciate some feedback on what I did wrong, and if I didn't, why this intuitively makes sense.
Proof. Let $C \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ an arbitrary set, then:
$$\begin{align*} \mu(C \cap A) + \mu(C \setminus A) &= \mu(C\cap A \cap B) + \mu((C \cap A) \setminus B) + \mu(C \setminus A) &(1)\\
&= \mu(C \cap B) + \mu(C \cap (A\setminus B)) + \mu(C \setminus A) &(2)\\
&\leq \mu(C \cap B) + \mu(A\setminus B) + \mu(C\setminus B) &(3)\\
&= \mu(C \cap B) + \mu(C \setminus B) &(4)\\
&= \mu(C) &(5)
 \end{align*}$$
I use the following properties for each equality/inequality:

Because $B$ is $\mu$-measurable, the following equality holds for all sets $E \subseteq \Bbb R^n$: $\mu(E)= \mu(E\cap B) + \mu(E \setminus B)$.

$B\subseteq A \implies A \cap B = B$ and $(C\cap A) \setminus B = (C\cap A)\cap B^c = C \cap (A \cap B^c) = C \cap (A\setminus B)$ follows from associativity of the intersection.

$C \cap (A \setminus B) \subseteq A\setminus B$ and $B \subseteq A \implies C\setminus A \subseteq C\setminus B$, so by monotonicity of the measure the inequality follows.

By assumption $\mu(A \setminus B) = 0$.

Same reasoning as step 1.


The reverse inequality follows from $\sigma$-subadditivity of the measure. $\square$
Thank you in advance.

What is $\mu$? Is it an outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

@AlexKruckman In my course on measure theory, a measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb R^n$ is defined as a map $\mu :  \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R^n) \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ such that $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ and for a set $A \subseteq \bigcup_{k\in \Bbb N} A_k : \mu(A) \leq \sum_{k \in \Bbb N} \mu(A_k)$. Furthermore $\mu$-measurability is defined by the Carathéodory Criterium as stated in 1 in my post. :)

Yes, your proof is correct. The claim is actually a consequence of a more general result: Given any outer measure $\mu$, the collection of $\mu$-measurable set is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ restricted to such $\sigma$-algebra is a complete measure.

What your course is calling a "measure" is what most people call an "outer measure". A measure is a slightly different concept (see Wikipedia). The relationship between outer measures and measures is summarized by @Ramiro's comment.

@AlexKruckman Thanks! That is good to know!

@Ramiro I see, thank you! I didn't think about the fact that it follows directly from that haha.
